# Present UIImagePickerController cause my app crash under iOS6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Code is below and crash at `[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];` when I use device under iOS6.1. It work fine in iOS 7.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Get the error in console: ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have fixed the bug, I want to share it out with detail process.

When it crashes, it shows **ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception** in the console, I have no idea about "ImageIO balabala..." but I think I may catch the exception when I noticed "libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception". So I add @try @catch in my code, code is below.

```
@try {
   [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES] ;
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception:%@", exception) ;
}
@finally {
}
```

Then I run it again, I got **exception:preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!**.

The problem seems to be a little obvious, after google it, I find a solution which is to override some orientation related methods to provide a preferred interface orientation in UIImagePickerController.

So I subclass the `UIImagePickerController` and implement some methods like this below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Then run again, no crash , cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

With

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Tried, but still crash.